# iOS: Method doesn't wait for the other methods it calls to finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, database

I have this model in one of my iPhone apps:

```
//
//  CatapultAccount.m
//  Catapult
//
//  Created by Aziz Light on 4/9/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Catapult Technology Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CatapultAccount.h"

@interface CatapultAccount ()

- (BOOL)createAccountsTable;

- (BOOL)accountWithNameIsAlreadyAdded:(NSString *)accountName;

- (NSDictionary *)getAccountLogosForClient:(NSDictionary *)client;

- (NSString *)getAccountLogoFromURL:(NSURL *)url;

- (NSString *)saveImage:(UIImage *)image
           withFileName:(NSString *)imageName
                 ofType:(NSString *)extension
            inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath;

@end

@implementation CatapultAccount

- (BOOL)createAccountWithAccountID:(NSString *)accountID
{
    __block BOOL operationSuccessfull;

    NXOAuth2Account *account = [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accountWithIdentifier:accountID];

    if (account == nil) {
        operationSuccessfull = NO;
    } else {
        if ([self openDatabaseConnection]) {
            if ([self createAccountsTable]) {

                [NXOAuth2Request performMethod:@"GET"
                                    onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/users/me", kCatapultHost]]
                               usingParameters:nil
                                   withAccount:account
                           sendProgressHandler:nil
                               responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error != nil) {
                                       operationSuccessfull = NO;
#if DEBUG
                                       NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
#endif
                                       _lastError = error;
                                   } else {
                                       NSError *jsonError;

                                       NSDictionary *serializedResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                                                                            error:&jsonError];

                                       if (jsonError != nil) {
                                           operationSuccessfull = NO;
#if DEBUG
                                           NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", jsonError);
#endif
                                           _lastError = jsonError;
                                       } else {
                                           NSDictionary *user   = [serializedResponse objectForKey:@"user"];
                                           NSDictionary *client = [serializedResponse objectForKey:@"client"];

                                           NSString *forename    = [user objectForKey:@"forename"];
                                           NSString *surname     = [user objectForKey:@"surname"];
                                           NSString *accountName = [client objectForKey:@"account_name"];
                                           NSString *clientName  = [client objectForKey:@"client_name"];

                                           if ([self accountWithNameIsAlreadyAdded:accountName]) {
                                               operationSuccessfull = NO;

                                               _lastError = [NSError errorWithDomain:kCatapultAccountErrorDomain
                                                                                code:kCatapultDuplicateAccountErrorCode
                                                                            userInfo:@{@"message": @"You have already added this account"}];

#if DEBUG
                                               NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", _lastError);
#endif
                                           } else {
                                               NSDictionary *logos = [self getAccountLogosForClient:client];

                                               operationSuccessfull = [self.db executeUpdate:@"insert into accounts(account_id, forename, surname, account_name, client_name, smallest_logo, thumb_logo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                                                                       accountID, forename, surname, accountName, clientName, logos[@"smallest_logo"], logos[@"thumb_logo"]];
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
                               }];

            } else {
                operationSuccessfull = NO;

                _lastError = [NSError errorWithDomain:kCatapultDatabaseErrorDomain
                                                 code:kCatapultUnableToCreateTableErrorCode
                                             userInfo:@{@"message": @"Unable to create the accounts table"}];

#if DEBUG
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", _lastError);
#endif
            }

            [self closeDatabaseConnection];
        } else {
            operationSuccessfull = NO;

            _lastError = [NSError errorWithDomain:kCatapultDatabaseErrorDomain
                                             code:kCatapultUnableToOpenDatabaseConnectionErrorCode
                                         userInfo:@{@"message": @"Unable to open database connection"}];

#if DEBUG
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", _lastError);
#endif
        }
    }

    return operationSuccessfull;
}

- (BOOL)createAccountsTable
{
    // Accounts table schema
    // id integer primary key autoincrement
    // account_id varchar(36) not null - unique
    // forename varchar(255) not null
    // surname varchar(255) not null
    // account_name varchar(255) not null - unique
    // client_name varchar(255) not null
    // smallest_account_logo text
    // thumb_account_logo text

    BOOL tableCreationWasSuccessfull = [self.db executeUpdate:@"create table if not exists accounts(id integer primary key autoincrement, account_id varchar(36) not null, forename varchar(255) not null, surname varchar(255) not null, account_name varchar(255) not null, client_name varchar(255) not null, smallest_logo text, thumb_logo text, unique(account_id, account_name) on conflict abort)"];

    if (tableCreationWasSuccessfull) {
        _lastError = nil;
    } else {
        _lastError = [self.db lastError];
#if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Failed to create users table: %@", _lastError);
#endif
    }

    return tableCreationWasSuccessfull;
}

- (BOOL)accountWithNameIsAlreadyAdded:(NSString *)accountName
{
    FMResultSet *account = [self.db executeQuery:@"select count(*) from accounts"];
    return [account next];
}

- (NSDictionary *)getAccountLogosForClient:(NSDictionary *)client
{
    NSString *smallestLogoURLString = [[[client objectForKey:@"logo"] objectForKey:@"smallest"] objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *smallestLogoPath = [self getAccountLogoFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:smallestLogoURLString]];

    NSString *thumbLogoURLString = [[[client objectForKey:@"logo"] objectForKey:@"thumb"] objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSString *thumbLogoPath = [self getAccountLogoFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbLogoURLString]];

    return @{@"smallest_logo": smallestLogoPath, @"thumb_logo": thumbLogoPath};
}

- (NSString *)getAccountLogoFromURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSString *urlWithoutGETParams = [[[url absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *lastSegmentOfURL = [[urlWithoutGETParams componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
    NSString *logoName = [[lastSegmentOfURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *logoExtension =  [[lastSegmentOfURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];

    NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *logoPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", logoName, logoExtension]];

    BOOL logoExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:logoPath];

    if (logoExists) {
        return logoPath;
    } else {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        logoPath = [self saveImage:logo withFileName:logoName ofType:logoExtension inDirectory:documentsDirectoryPath];

        return (logoPath == nil) ? nil : logoPath;
    }
}

- (NSString *)saveImage:(UIImage *)image
           withFileName:(NSString *)imageName
                 ofType:(NSString *)extension
            inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath
{
    NSData *imageRepresentation;

    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"gif"]) {
        imageRepresentation = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        imageRepresentation = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    } else {
#if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG/GIF)", extension);
#endif
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *imagePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, extension]];

    NSError *error;
    BOOL imageDidSave = [imageRepresentation writeToFile:imagePath
                                                 options:NSAtomicWrite
                                                   error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
#if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Error saving the file: %@", error);
#endif
    }

    return (imageDidSave) ? imagePath : nil;
}

@end
```

And this method in one of my view controllers:

```
- (void)createAccount:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NXOAuth2Account *account = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"NXOAuth2AccountStoreNewAccountUserInfoKey"];

    if ([_accountModel createAccountWithAccountID:account.identifier]) {
        // Do something
        NSLog(@"Yay");
    } else {
        // Delete the newly created account
        [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] removeAccount:account];

        UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Account Error"
                                                               message:@"Unable to add new account"
                                                              delegate:nil
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [errorMessage show];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is that, following my (naive) observations, most of the methods that use the database in the model execute too slowly and the `createAccountWithAccountID:` method doesn't wait for the method it calls to finish. The result of that is that the record is not saved to the database but for some reason the `createAccountWithAccountID` method returns `YES`… here are the logs that illustrate what I am saying:

```
2013-04-09 20:07:46.261 Catapult[21004:c07] Yay
2013-04-09 20:07:46.276 Catapult[21004:c07] The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x7288300> is not open.
2013-04-09 20:07:46.606 Catapult[21004:c07] The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x7288300> is not open.
```

The record is not saved to the database because the database connection gets closed too fast…

Does anybody know how I can solve my problem please?

Comment: Keep in mind that you're using a non-Apple API there, so most folks here have never heard of it.  You're the one who must examine the documentation for NXOAuth2Request to see what it does -- you can't expect others to do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most methods which use a completion block execute asynchronously. The method will return immediately and the block will be executed when the request actually completes. You need to handle it accordingly in your code. Don't release anything after you send the request, but do anything that depends on the result in the response handler block and then release it.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Following your advice, and the advice from IRC people, I added a completion handler to the `createAccountWithAccountID:` method and did some other refactoring and I fixed my problem.